# Xcode/git not working with subfolders

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have git set up with my Xcode project. I'm trying to add a subfolder (e.g. My Project Dir/Resources) and track changes. However, after I drag the subfolder into Xcode, it's not being change tracked. Why?

Comment: did you check "Copy items into destination folder(if needed)" ?

Comment: I just dragged the folder into the Xcode. But the folder is located inside the project directory, so it should be good to go, right?

Comment: git only works with folders inside the target directory, so confirm that it's there by looking in the Finder and not just in your Xcode project structure. Go into the file properties panel as well and make sure the file/folder is actually under source control as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Drag the folder to Xcode. Make sure it is either in the right place or that you also copy it.
2. Select the files in the project browser and choose "File->Source Control->Add". Alternatively, hit <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.

Alternatively, go to your directory in Terminal and type

```
   git add NewFolder
```

Comment: Add is greyed out. But doing `xcrun git add …` worked. Why can't I do this in Xcode?